# Need data from another table in DB to generate e-mail without additional query

Tags: vba, database, email, ms-access

So I have a db with two tables. One, "Recipients", contains individuals names or distro list names, their department within the company, and their email address. The second, "Sites", contains information about different locations where the company has offices. The data in these two tables are not related.

I want to click a button on the Sites form that linked to the data in the Sites table to email information about the site in the record that is displayed to everyone in the Recipients table, based on their section or position. For example, the email is sent to everyone in the Sales department, and the supervisors and managers would be CC'd,

I have the VBA script completed except for looking up the e-mail addresses and populating the To and CC address fields. I could hard code the e-mail addresses, but I am building this for other members of my office to use, and would like them to be able to update the e-mail list when an employee leaves, gets added or is replaced without having to learn how to interpret the code. Everything else is working satisfactorily.

I am using Office 365, my script is below.

---

```
Private Sub Command106_Click()

     'Set up outlook
     Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
     Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

     'Create message
    strbody = "<p style='font-size:15'>" & "All," & "<br>" & _
            "<br>" & _
            "Please see the office information below for " & Me.CompanySiteID.Value & "." & "<br>" & _
            "<br>" & _
            "Address: " & "&nbsp;&nbsp;" & Me.Address.Value & "<br>" & _
            "City: " & "&nbsp;&nbsp;" & Me.City.Value & "<br>" & _
            "State: " & "&nbsp;&nbsp;" & Me.State.Value & "<br>" & _
            " Size: " & "&nbsp;&nbsp;" & Me. Size.Value & "<br>" & _

    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .Display
        .to = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = " Office Information below for " & Me.CompanySiteID.Value
        .HTMLBody = strbody & .HTMLBody
        '.Send
    End With
   
     'Delete any temp files created
      Kill strPath & strFName
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove this: `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: Open a filtered recordset of Recipients in VBA and loop through records to build address string for To or BCC or CC. Building address string from recordset is a common topic, many examples.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898560/send-email-to-every-contact-in-a-table-access-vba